# How to print top most y-axis tick in ggplot2 geombar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar chart with my y-axis showing proportions (0-1), however, as seen in the image below, the top most y tick (which should be "1") is not printed.  How do I rectify this?

[image]

Here is my code for reference:

```
ggplot(DATA4, aes(fill = FACTOR, y = VALUE, x = GROUP)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + labs(fill = "TEXT") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey75","grey60","grey45")) +
  theme_mine() + 
  xlab("TEXT") +
  ylab("TEXT") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

Comment: Is your data's top value 1, or just close? The `expand = c(0,0)` tells ggplot that the axis shouldn't go any farther than the extent of the data. You could specify larger expansion, or remove the term altogether to get default expansion, which I think is 5%.

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring. My top value is only close to 1.  I see what you mean about `expand = c(0,0)`.  Im using that code to make the origin of my axes 0.   Can you suggest how to do that and have the top tick printed at the same time?

Comment: Try adding `+  expand_limits(y = 1)` after what you have.

Comment: Thankyou @JonSpring, That worked perfectly.

Sorry all - This seemed to be stupidly simple problem (although I did research online beforehand and came ups empty handed).